# How to get all permutations of sizes {n, n-1,n-2, ... 1} from list of size n efficiently?

Tags: python, performance, permutation

I am trying to find all permutations from a list that are the same size or smaller than the list.

For example:

```
>>>allPermutations([a,b])
[[a,b], [b,a], [a], [b]]
```

This is the iterative code I currently have in python. I'm not sure how efficient it currently is.

```
import itertools

def getAllPossibleSubSchedules( seq ):
    fullSet = set()
    curSet = set()
    curSet.add(tuple(seq))
    for i in reversed(range(1, len(seq) + 1)):
        permutations = set()
        for curTuple in curSet:
            permutationsList = list(itertools.permutations(curTuple, i))
            for permutation in permutationsList:
                permutations.add(permutation)
        curSet = set()
        for permutation in permutations:
            curSet.add(permutation)
            fullSet.add(permutation)
    return fullSet
```

I'm pretty sure the algorithm will produce the **summation of n! from 1 -> n** permutations which grows pretty quickly. So far I have created a recursive way to do it that is incredibly slow because it does many repeated operations. I have been trying to do it through iteration but I can't figure out how to limit repeated operations. I am using python but psuedo-code would also help me a lot. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't this be tougher than finding the powerset of a given set? As it's a similar problem with ordering added on top of that. I'm just asking out of curiosity because I think that's what _they_ call an "NP-complete" problem.

Comment: @Mariano who are "them"? In short (non-complete) an NP-complete problem is a problem that can solve another NP-complete problem with a polylog translation time. That has nothing to do with the time complexity.

Comment: "They" are the people who know about this stuff, a group of which I am not part, which is why I asked. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 4):

The following should work:

```
from itertools import permutations

def allPermutations(seq):
    return (x for i in range(len(seq),0,-1) for x in permutations(seq, i))
```

For example:

```
>>> list(allPermutations('abc'))
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 'b'), ('c', 'b', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'a'), ('c', 'b'), ('a',), ('b',), ('c',)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe iterate over all permutations for lists with all possible sizes. To clarify:

```
def all_permutations(input_list):
    for i in xrange(len(input_list)):
        sublist = input_list[:i]
        for variant in permutations(sublist):
            yield variant
```

Answer (score -1):

I am pretty sure your `permutations.add()` and `curSet.add()` and `fullSet.add()` calls are going to cause your routine to crawl to a halt very quickly. If you keep changing the size of an array, the memory allocated will "run out of space" and a new location has to be found. This means that the entire array gets copied. And then you add another element - rinse and repeat.

You need to compute the number of elements you need, and pre-allocate the space for that. Thus, if you have 5 elements, you need to allocate ( 5! + 5*4! + 10*3! + 10*2! + 5 ) x 5 elements for the final result - and less for the intermediate results. Then you fill these array without shuffling blocks of memory around; it will make things significantly faster.